# Why is my app crashing when I try to set the value of this variable in prepareForSegue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6, segue

The gist of what I'm trying to do is set the value of a label on the window I'm segueing to the text that the user entered on the previous window.

The user segues by clicking "Read", which segues them.

Here's my prepareForSegue method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    ReadingViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;

    destination.textToRead = self.textInput.text;
}
```

`textToRead` is just an NSString object that holds the text that the user enters. (This text is then set as a label with the `viewDidLoad` method.)

The window that is segued to is set as a different view controller as expected (ReadingViewController) and I created the segue by control-dragging from the "Read" UIButton to the next window.

I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. Here's the error it gives:

```
2013-03-13 19:00:08.119 Project Lego[1523:c07] -[UINavigationController setTextToRead:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x894d230
2013-03-13 19:00:08.122 Project Lego[1523:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setTextToRead:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x894d230'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c92012 0x10cfe7e 0x1d1d4bd 0x1c81bbc 0x1c8194e 0x2949 0x45bb87 0x45bc14 0x10e3705 0x172c0 0x17258 0xd8021 0xd857f 0xd76e8 0x46cef 0x46f02 0x24d4a 0x16698 0x1beddf9 0x1bedad0 0x1c07bf5 0x1c07962 0x1c38bb6 0x1c37f44 0x1c37e1b 0x1bec7e3 0x1bec668 0x13ffc 0x244d 0x2375 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access the view controller embedded in a navigationVC, do something like this:

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
    {
        UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        ReadingViewController *destination = [nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        destination.textToRead = self.textInput.text;
     }
```

Comment: Beautiful answer, worked exactly how I wanted, thank you. (I might add however that `UINavigationController` is the class you're looking for.)

Comment: Haha yeah woops i had it right without the cast..ill fix..my bad, typing off the cuff

Answer (score 1):

Your segue is referencing the `UINavigationController`, not your viewcontroller class.  Check your Storyboard to make sure the segue is connecting the right controllers.

Comment: You're right, that was it indeed. Only, I want to have it embedded in a navigation controller so it can have a navigation bar to put my cancel button in (so I can dismiss the modal view). Is there a way to embed it in the navigation controller and still have this work?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be setting textToRead on the Navigation controller. I am assuming you want to set this in the view controller. If so you need to

```
    if ([segue.destinationViewController 
                 isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
    {
       mvc = (ReadingViewController *) [segue.destinationViewController topViewController];
       mvc.textToRead = self.textInput.text; 

    } else {

       ReadingViewController *destination = segue.destinationViewController;
       destination.textToRead = self.textInput.text;
   }
```